# Java 11 TLDScanner not loading system TLDs

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, taglib

I have few jsp files which use taglibs example

- jsp/jstl/core which is system tld
- jsp-tiles

which are not getting loaded by the TLDScanner( from javax.servlet.jsp 2.3.2) since

1. there is a check in the code (jstl-1.2.jar) to see if the
   classloader is an instance of URLClassLoader , From Java 11 the
   ApplicationClassloader is not a URLClassloader it does not load the
   tld
2. tried adding the jstl-1.2.jar in web-inf/lib this also does not work since when isLocal is true it does not load system tlds

Note: the issue does not exist when we use tomcat since tomcat has a TLDScanner which does not work like this and is able to load the TLDs in Java 11

Can some one tell me how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is basically issue with jettys TLD Scanner, the issue is not there with embedded tomcat

not sure if latest jetty has fixed this issue.